# Want to get a notification on mobile of new post if any new post on my wordpress blog?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, webview

I have created a `android app using webview`.

> I want to show my users (who has installed my android app ) a notification of new blog posts.
>
> When user click on that notification Url should be opened in webview.

I tried like this tutorial.

```
mNotificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
// Sets an ID for the notification, so it can be updated
int notifyID = 1;
mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setContentTitle("New Message")
    .setContentText("You've received new messages.")
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notify_status)
numMessages = 0;
// Start of a loop that processes data and then notifies the user
...
    mNotifyBuilder.setContentText(currentText)
        .setNumber(++numMessages);
    // Because the ID remains unchanged, the existing notification is
    // updated.
    mNotificationManager.notify(
            notifyID,
            mNotifyBuilder.build());
```

> But i'm newbie, this is not at all working

Also tried this code in `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {`

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, yourwebviewactivity.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

 NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

 Notification noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(icon_small)
                    .setTicker("ticker message")
                    .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
                    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .setContentTitle("title")
                    .setContentText("message")
                    .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                    //At most three action buttons can be added
                    .setAutoCancel(true).build();
notificationManager.notify(notifyID, noti);
```

Comment: your app contains web view activity right.

Comment: yes my app contains a link of my blog. by using `webview` i'm showing it on mobile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `Notification Intent Activity` like:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, yourwebviewactivity.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

 NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

 Notification noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(icon_small)
                    .setTicker("ticker message")
                    .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
                    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .setContentTitle("title")
                    .setContentText("message")
                    .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                    //At most three action buttons can be added
                    .setAutoCancel(true).build();
notificationManager.notify(notifyID, noti);
```

Do not forget to Register your webview `Activity` in `manifest.xml`

For more information go to: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Comment: `context` is undefined :(
giving it is giving me popup to use getBaseContext() ??

Comment: could you please share any link or tutorial for the same ?

Comment: hi I have tried above code but giving me error for `context` 
also let me know how I will get notification when new Post is there on my website? i'm using webview to show

Comment: @ashuthinks ok post your code where you create this notification.

Comment: inside protected void onCreate method I tried your code

Comment: @ashuthinks oh my goodness. if you are implement in `Activity` then pass `Activity` context directly like `Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(youractivity.this, yourwebviewactivity.class);`

Comment: ok but are you sure this will give me notification if Any new post is there in my blog? which i'm showing in webview as my android app?

Comment: is it like 
 `Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity.class);`
sorry i'm new in this

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49056/discussion-between-ashuthinks-and-simple-plan)