# How to give onclick event to android menu?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, menuitem

I have created android app using webview and added menu's into it.

```
In main.xml code

<item android:id="@+id/interview_tips" android:title="@string/interview_tips"></item>
<item android:id="@+id/interview_tips" android:title="@string/interview_tips"></item>
<item android:id="@+id/career_trend" android:title="@string/career_trend"></item>
<item android:id="@+id/video_hub" android:title="@string/video_hub"></item>
```

which is giving me menus like following image.

> when I clicked on any menu I want to open a URL in same webview, How can I do it

I tried like this which is not working

```
    //menu click event
        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle item selection
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
            if (item.isChecked()) item.setChecked(false);
            else item.setChecked(true);
            mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");            
            return true;            
        case R.id.career_trend:
            if (item.isChecked()) item.setChecked(false);
            else item.setChecked(true);
            mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");        
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

I'm bit new in android please give me any link , tutorial? 
[image]

Comment: `webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");`

Comment: @VenomVendor I did the same for WebView , but what about Menu's ? Every menu is having different URL?

Comment: get the item position from `onItemSelected`, `url =  arrayOfUrl[position]`.

Comment: @VenomVendor Can you please provide me any tutorial link or code snippet I'm totally new to android :( thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  [onOptionItemSelected](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onOptionsItemSelected%28android.view.MenuItem%29) if you use a Menu.

Also look a [Menus guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html) and an [Example : How to use menus.](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Creating_and_Managing_Overflow_Menus_on_Android)

And using a **WebView** required **INTERNET** permission, add below into AndroidManifest.xml.

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Also you can try enabling webview JS.

```
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

### UPDATE

First of all change your code

```
//menu click event
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

        case R.id.career_trend:
            mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
        }
        return true;
    }
```

### TO

```
//menu click event
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
        return true; 
        case R.id.career_trend:
            mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
        return true;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

**Secondary** - make sure that your webview is present on screen. I mean is visible...

**Third** - check INTERNET PERMISSION in your manifest file.

and **LAST!** - make sure that your **menu click listener is working**. Just put Log into `onOptionItemSelected` method and check that he printed.

Also look **WEB VIEW EXAMPLE** : http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-webview-example/

Comment: thanks I have updated my code please check and let me know where i'm goes wrong?

Comment: @ashuthinks are you add Permission to use Internet in your App?

Comment: Yes I did the same still onclick on menu URL is not opening :/

Comment: thanks a lot its working perfectly 
can you help me in this notification question please 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22173142/want-to-get-a-notification-on-mobile-of-new-post-if-any-new-post-on-my-wordpress

Answer (score 0):

String[] mListOfUrls = { "http://google.com", "http://go.com", "http://gle.com" };

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
        int pos, long id) {
   Log.wtf("URL", mListOfUrls[pos]);
   webView.loadUrl(mListOfUrls[pos]); 
}
```

Refer : [Spinner Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html)

Refer : [Spinner methods](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html)

http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-spinner-drop-down-list-example/

Comment: thanks one doubt i'm not using spinner i guess its `menu item in main.xml` ?